# Difference between <template iterate="..."> and <template repeat="...">

Tags: dart

I've seen a few Dart examples/tutorials that look like `<template iterate="thing in collection">` and others that use `<template repeat="thing in collection">`. They seem to do exactly the same thing. What's the difference between them and why is one recommended instead of the other in a given situation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's straight from the changelog:

> Added 'template-repeat' that, unlike template-iterate, if used as an
>   attribute it repeats the tag instead of the children of the tag.

The reason is that following HTML is invalid for most HTML parsers:

```
<select>
  <template iterate='name in results'>
    <option>{{name}}</option>
  </template>
</select>`
```

`template` tag is not allowed within `select`, [so the solution is to use](http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=10537&can=1&q=iterate%20repeat&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Area%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary):

```
<select>
  <option template repeat='name in results'>{{name}}</option>
</select>
```

`template repeat` was added recently (April 2013), and it will replace `template iterate` eventually, AFAIK, but at the moment both are supported.